# Does iPhone 5s slow down with iOS 8?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am pondering whether it makes sense to install iOS 8 on my iPhone 5s.  I've seen articles like [this](http://gizmodo.com/dont-put-ios-8-on-your-iphone-4s-1635763610?utm_campaign=socialflow_gizmodo_facebook&utm_source=gizmodo_facebook&utm_medium=socialflow), that advise you not to install the new OS on the 4s.

However, I've seen nothing about the 5s experiences.  Those with 5s phones upgraded... did the phone slow down at all?  Was it worth it?

Comment: I think, yes it slows down a little. Functionality wise it is normal. But on calls it is slow now. I have noticed that my phone vibrates first and then its screen turns on. secondly, it is slow when you pick the calls. I think apple has failed to meet the stability of IOS 6. I only upgraded to iPhone 5S because Apple forced me to do so. I was quite happy with my old iPhone 4 but iOS 7 release just ruined it and I had to upgrade to 5s.

Answer (score 5):

My 5s didn't slow down at all after the upgrade. I did disable a few features that annoyed me (quicktype prediction, spotlight suggestions, etc.) and you may want to if you're concerned about performance, but I didn't notice any speed issues at all. Much, much better than my experience with the beta on an iPod Touch.

Answer (score 2):

I've been running iOS 8 on a 5 since the first beta, and I've noticed no difference in normal use.  The only thing I can even think to comment on is that the boot time seems longer than before.

Since it works so nicely on a 5, I can't imagine that you'd have an issues on a 5s.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for me, I've been seeing slow response in certain apps after the upgrade. I cannot prove that it was due to iOS8 but I am seeing more of it than before.

Edit: This issue will most likely occur until the app updates for iOS8, till then stability and bugs may occur.